# Watch Events with same Name but different params

Tags: web3js, javascript, events

using web3@0.0.xx is there a way to get Events overloaded (with the same name, but different params) ?

I found

```
contract.Transfer[‘address,address,uint256,address,bytes’]({
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: ‘latest’
}).watch(function(error, event) {
    console.log(error, event)
})

contract.Transfer[‘address,address,uint256’]({
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: ‘latest’
}).watch(function(error, event) {
    console.log(error, event)
})
```

But I'm wondering if there is a generic way for doing it